# MySql Sum and Count for simple table

Tags: mysql

Could you help me with simple table SUM and COUNT calculating?

I've simple table 'test'

```
id name value
1  a    4
2  a    5
3  b    3
4  b    7
5  b    1
```

I need calculate SUM and Count for "a" and "b". I try this sql request:

```
SELECT name, SUM( value ) AS val, COUNT( * ) AS count FROM  `test`
```

result:

```
name val count
a    20  5
```

But should be

```
name val count
a    9   2
b    11  3
```

Could you help me with correct sql request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `GROUP BY`. That will cause the query to return a count and sum per group you defined (in this case, per name).

Without `GROUP BY` you just get the totals and any of the names (in your case 'a', but if could just as well have been 'b').

```
SELECT name, SUM( value ) AS val, COUNT( * ) AS count 
FROM  `test` 
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `group by`

```
select 
name, 
sum(value) as value, 
count(*) as `count` 
from test group by name ;
```